# Is there any way that i can implement a premade USBHID driver into my kernel that im building?

Tags: c, assembly, input, kernel, usb

this is my first time posting on SE i believe.
I would like to know wether or not it would be theoretically possible to implement a already existing usb-kbd driver in a kernel written in c, or would i have to reinvent the wheel and make a custom usb hub/ controller/ kbd driver to input a string?
What im trying to do is i am trying to make a CLI for the beforementioned kernel, so i can get input from the user and not only output to the screen.
I have all the code published on https://github.com/devbrones/milk
(yes its called milk.....)
(also the majority of the scripts are based upon the linux journals tutorial on how to make a simple kernel, i thought i wanted to build upon it.)

Comment: So, do you want to **reuse** an existing driver written for Linux in the your own kernel? You hardly can do that since a typical Linux driver uses many functions provided by the kernel core, so you need to have these functions implemented for your kernel too.

Comment: To have USB you need to implement Host USB stack. There is no other way.

Comment: IIRC, USB has a "simple" mode or something that works for keyboards.  Or of course x86 PCs booted in legacy mode will emulate a PS/2 keyboard for you with the help of the chipset, although I don't know how long that keeps working.  (Whether it keeps working in protected mode with your own IDT, via system-management-mode, or whether it's only in real mode.)  https://wiki.osdev.org/USB_Human_Interface_Devices

Comment: @PeterCordes so i could theoretically make a ps2 interpreter stack or something and let the computer handle the conversion frm simple mode usb to ps2?

Comment: Yeah, if you don't mind your toy OS only working when booted in legacy BIOS mode, not UEFI.  And again only on hardware + firmware that supports USB emulation (as PS2).  Most people wouldn't call it a "ps2 stack", though; it's a pretty simple hardware interface with an I/O port.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you for taking time and explaining! im quite new to low level programming. Im currently only running the kernel through a qemu emulator, and i dont really mind if the kernel only has legacy support :D. As long as i can get started with testing basic Input and Output i will be really happy :DD

Comment: https://wiki.osdev.org/%228042%22_PS/2_Controller#USB_Legacy_Support.  Or of course you can use the legacy BIOS `int 0x10` interface if you're actually in real mode, instead of switching to protected or long mode.